# WooCommerce new order action - get order information

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this to create a new function in my `functions.php` file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'create_invoice_for_wc_order',  1, 1  );
function create_invoice_for_wc_order() {

}
```

it is to execute some custom code when a new order is placed, how can i get the order information (ordered products etc) inside my function

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `$order_id` as a parameter for your `woocommerce_new_order` callback and get the order details from the `$order_id`.

Example:

```
// define the woocommerce_new_order callback 
function create_invoice_for_wc_order( $order_id ) { 
    // get order details data...
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    var_dump($order);
};
```

References:

http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_new_order/

https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html

Comment: ive tried inserting `var_dump($order)` into a database but its just blank

Comment: You may try with `woocommerce_order_status_completed` or `woocommerce_payment_complete` action.

Comment: i want it to be for new orders - when an order is placed through the website or wp-admin

Comment: The above two actions are actually for new orders.

Answer (score 15):

All answers here are correct but if you need the line items the above wont work since line items can't be fetched with new WC_Order at that time.

The hook now has a second `$order` parameter that will work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'create_invoice_for_wc_order',  1, 2  );
function create_invoice_for_wc_order( $order_id, $order ) {
    $items = $order->get_items();
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.  This is proper and avoids all of the other nasty workarounds.

Comment: This is gold.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

`woocommerce_new_order` includes an `$order_id` parameter. You can use it in your callback:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'create_invoice_for_wc_order',  1, 1  );
function create_invoice_for_wc_order( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: You can use `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id )`

Comment: i tried this, then i have tried inserting `print_r($order_id);` into a database table which inserts `1`

Comment: is the `woocommerce_new_order` the correct action to use for when a new order is added?

Comment: @charlie The value 1 is because print_r() directly prints out the output and returns true (1). Use print_r($order_id, true) if you want to use the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only the order details, You can use 'woocommerce_new_order' hook and $order_id as parameter

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'create_invoice_for_wc_order',  1, 1  );
function create_invoice_for_wc_order($order_id) {
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
print_r($order);
//your code
}
```

But if You want to get order items You should use 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed'

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'create_invoice_for_wc_order',  1, 1  );
function create_invoice_for_wc_order($order_id) {
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
//order items
$items = $order->get_items();
print_r($items);
}
```