# Save WooCommerce Order to Another Database

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce store and it as usually saves Order Data in WordPress database. I have created a separate database `order_master` in which I want to store the WooCommerce Order.

For this, I have defined a separate database in `wp-config` as:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db   = 'order_master';
```

So, Can an external database could be used to save WooCommerce Order details? If yes, Then I would really appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: Do you want to save wp orders data in to another database?

Comment: but... they have their own table? is that not enough? 
Getting it to work the other woocommerce functions, like get_order(); etc, might not be easy.

Comment: Yeah, It stores in WordPress database but I want to save details on an external server MySQL database.

Comment: you could hook in on the order functions (save, update etc) and send the details to your other DB as well as the native one, but then you have it in two tables/DBs

Comment: which hook could be used to do this?

Comment: all of the hooks are listed here : https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: but I would look into `woocommerce_update_order` and `woocommerce_new_order` -

Comment: Keep in mind, I don't know what data you require in you new db - There might be a lot of work ahead for you!

Comment: I need only `order-id` and `amount` to be saved

Comment: http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_new_order/ might be easier to understand than the docs

Comment: example on how to call it, has been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868183/woocommerce-new-order-action-get-order-information