# WooCommerce - When order is created?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing a PHP script and need to retrieve an order id. My question is, at what point is the order created and when could I edit it? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: You need to use a hook. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868183/woocommerce-new-order-action-get-order-information

Comment: The hook: `woocommerce_new_order`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the order late or at any time just pass order_id(eg.115) and perform the operation accordingly

```
add_action('init',function(){
  $order_id = 115;
  if($order_id){
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $order->update_status('wc-processing'); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many hooks that allow update order to create a new order

few are :

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_new_order', 10, 1);
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'woocommerce_new_order', 10, 1 );
```

You can use one of them(not both at a time)

Full Example:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_new_order', 10, 1);

function woocommerce_new_order($order_id){
    //update_option('new_order', $order_id );
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
}
```

Here you got order_id and order(full order info).
Now you can add/update/delete anything accordingly.

Comment: What to do when I want to only add/change something to existing order (Woocommerce create order and i want to edit this later)?